# Uniform convergence on compact subsets implies uniform convergence on relatively compact subsets?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces

We have $f_n\colon X \to Y$ is an operator between Banach spaces. Suppose that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on compact subsets in $x$. This means that if $x \in K \subset X$ where $K$ is compact, then the rate of convergence is independent of $x$ (but depends on $K$).

Suppose that $C$ is relatively compact, so that its closure is compact. Then since $C \subset \bar C$, we
get $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on $x \in C$.

Is this right?

Why doesn't this property ("uniform on relatively compact subsets") get stated in literature?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Why doesn't this property get stated in literature?  Probably because it's an immediate consequence of the former (as you yourself noted) and takes more words.